# Can we change the minimum Flash Player requirement for Flex 4.6 SDK to 10.2?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5, flex4.6

Is it possible to change the minimum Flash Player required to version 10.2 for Flex 4.6 SDK? Currently the minimum required by the SDK is 11.1.

If it is possible to change it what would happen when someone views our application in Flash Player 10.2? Will it still run? Are there API's that we can stay away from in our Application? You know what I'm trying to say...

Comment: Why is it necessary? They adoption rates of the latest version of Flash are so high that it really would not be worth the trouble.

Comment: That's good to know but unfortunately some institutions are slow to upgrade and would require considerable effort to upgrade them or convince them to upgrade. Getting the answers to this question will help me determine the action to take.

Comment: While this is true, Flash adoption rates are _insanely_ high. Adobe touts 90-95% of Flash users running the latest version of Flash once or twice a year. Unless you know for a fact that your target audience does not use the latest version of Flash, it's likely best to take the updated features and better security and let go of that 5-10% who has not updated, especially when it will be incredibly difficult to determine what you can and cannot use in the 4.6 SDK. If you must, though, you could downgrade to the 4.5 SDK.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and I agree for the most part. I'm mostly trying to get information on the whole thing, mostly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer to that is: it depends.

It depends on which features of Flash Player you use. If nothing in your application uses any new features, it will run seamlessly in an older VM.

However it could be a daunting task to find out if there are any dependencies, because they could be buried deep in the Flex framework. So basically you would have to know the framework code from end to end. Or you'd just have to test your application in the older VM and see if everything still works as expected.

If you wish to target a different player version than the default, use the `target-player` compiler option; e.g.:

```
-target-player=10.2
```

Comment: So is there a way I can trick it into accepting or compiling 10.2 or 10.3? Or do I just set the min version in the HTML Wrapper page?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to target Flash Player 10.2, I suggest you use [Flex SDK 4.5](http://sourceforge.net/adobe/flexsdk/wiki/Flex%204.5/) instead of 4.6. The feature sets aren't vastly different, and it will let you support Flash Player 10.1 as well.

It is possible to install an older SDK into the current Flash Builder, but in this case it's probably easier to just install Flash Builder 4.5 instead.

If you require some feature that is only in Flex SDK 4.6+, it stands to reason you probably need the newer player. Adobe didn't move up the player requirement for no reason.